# why my react code not working?

Tags: reactjs

Everyone I am new to `reactjs` .I don't want to use react-create app . So, I have created two file , but when I am executing it , it does not do any thing . I'm getting blank page. why ?
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Welcome />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Where do you include app.js file?

Comment: Please go through the article first : https://medium.com/@robhitt/react-from-scratch-575d1e570b85

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add these cdn

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.1/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**babel** is required to compile your es6 code

you also need to give path od components in your react app

```
  <script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
```

I think you have missed bundle.js also where all your react code will be compiled.so you need to define its path also as

```
<script src="js/bundle.js">
```

configure it in webpack as

```
  module.exports = {
          entry: './App.jsx',
          output: {
            path: __dirname + '/', 
            filename: 'bundle.js' 
          },
```

and give path to this file

Comment: @MirthfulNahid If you want to use ES5 or later ECMA script, you need to know babel or something that transpile like babel.

Comment: Please go through react,babe and webpack before proceeding further:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no error on your react code. However you don't import `app.js` file on html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

</body>
<script src="path/to/app.js"> </script><!-- You need to add this code and modify path.-->
</html>
```

Comment: please let me know any message that inspector says.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution . 
i added a script tag

```
<script src="./browser.min.js"></script>
```

i not using any localhost. just loading the index page. it work.